# Why is the purpose of functional interfaces in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning Kotlin and I came across Functional Interfaces here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions, and I don't quite understand the purpose of declaring and using an interface like in the example. The example is as follows:

```
fun interface IntPredicate {
   fun accept(i: Int): Boolean
}

// Creating an instance of a class
val isEven = object : IntPredicate {
   override fun accept(i: Int): Boolean {
       return i % 2 == 0
   }
}

// Or creating an instance using lambda
val isEven = IntPredicate { it % 2 == 0 }


fun main() {
   println("Is 7 even? - ${isEven.accept(7)}")
}
```

Now why do this when we can declare a function isEven and then call it whenever we want, like this:

```
fun isEven(i: Int): Boolean {
    return i % 2 == 0
}

fun main() {
   println("Is 7 even? - ${isEven(7)}")
}
```

And we get the same result. I think I am missing something here, can anybody help with an explanation.
Now I get what lambda expression is but what does exactly these lines of code do (I have seen before in other files but didn't understand it)

```
// Creating an instance of a class
val isEven = object : IntPredicate {
   override fun accept(i: Int): Boolean {
       return i % 2 == 0
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: From documentation `If your API accepts a more complex entity than a function – for example, it has non-trivial contracts and/or operations on it that can't be expressed in a functional type's signature – declare a separate functional interface for it.`

Comment: Yes @cutiko, but what is the difference between declaring the interface to call a function and to call a function directly like I did ?

Comment: You would have to instantiate the class containing the function and then use `::` or have top level functions available for the entire project. Think about it passing it in an argument `If your API accepts a more complex entity than a function`

Comment: 'Think about it passing it in an argument If your API accepts a more complex entity than a function' <-  I am not sure what are you trying to explain to me, can you give me an example ? What to pass as an argument and where ?

Comment: `fun foo(sam: Sam)` that function now receives a formal structure instead of a lambda

Comment: sorry but I am not understanding this :/

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really about Kotlin and functional interfaces, but about fundamental concepts of object oriented programming. The question you ask is: why do we need interfaces if we can just use normal classes/functions? It is to abstract software components; to decouple caller of the function and its implementation.

Imagine we have a function that is used to filter a list of integers. It doesn't know rules for filtering, it receives them from external code in the form of `IntPredicate`. It could be declared as:

```kotlin
fun filterList(list: List<Int>, predicate: IntPredicate): List<Int> = TODO()

interface IntPredicate {
    fun accept(i: Int): Boolean
}
```

Because we have to provide an implementation of `IntPredicate`, using this function is quite cumbersome. For each use we need another implementation of `IntPredicate`. Even if we need to perform a very simple filtering, like looking for odd numbers. This seems like a much of work for such a simple case.

Functional interfaces and SAM conversions makes such cases much easier to use. After declaring predicate interface as `fun interface IntPredicate`, we can use our function like this:

```kotlin
filterList(list) { it % 2 == 0 }
```

Now, we can provide lambda instead of implementing a whole class.

Functional interfaces are not something entirely new, they won't let you do anything that would be not possible without them. By marking interface as `fun` we just enable a useful syntactic sugar for this interface.

Note that in practice my example does not make too much sense. We already have a very similar `filter()` function in stdlib, and in Kotlin we usually prefer function types over interfaces in such cases.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and explanation, but I still have some questions:
- This example shows when to use the interface, but this doesn't look like a real case scenario to me, unfortunately almost all examples are like this. If I need to filter a list there are a lot of ready methods which with some added logic from us can do the same thing.(like we don't need to reinvent the wheel). So my question is: is this something that I should just know because is asked on interviews or are there any real applications  
 e.g in Android Development or just in Kotlin?

Comment: What is the need to have a function for filtering a list of number that doesn't know the rules of filtering ?
If I need to filter my list a numbers I just create a function 'filterMyNumbers()' and then add the logic there and call it whenever I want.

Comment: These questions are really about OOP fundamentals. Interfaces weren't invented for interviews. Half of the code of well designed projects uses interfaces instead of classes. If it doesn't make sense to create filter that doesn't know filtering rules, then what about `filter()` function from stdlib? Is it meaningless just because it doesn't know how to filter? No, it just focuses on how to iterate over the source collection and how to create a new collection in an efficient way, but it doesn't really understand what does it filter or how does it filter. @Notron

Comment: I got it, thanks @broot . I am not continuing this thread more, can you at least suggest any book or course when I can learn OOP fundamentals ?

Comment: Why is SAM needed here? You could do the same with higher order functions. I always thought this was mostly a Java compatibility thing.

Comment: @Cyril I agree, function types are much more "kotlin-ish" than SAMs and I personally almost never use fun interfaces. I think interfaces may be preferable for: Java interop, for specifying a meaningful name, for giving it a distinct "type identify" (e.g. `CoroutineScope` - it is basically a `CoroutineContext` provider) or if the interface is intended to be extended and implemented by classes, but still it is often used as lambdas (e.g. `Comparator`). But as I said, I almost never use it myself.

Comment: This is confusing :/ , the stackoverflow was my last option since I already tried google, youtube, different books but still can find a proper answer to this(The use of interfaces in OOP for callbacks and the use like the example I posted above). 
I guess I have to continue using these just as I see in other examples and don't know what I am doing in background :/

Comment: @Notron You think about it too much. `fun interface` is just a tiny QoL improvement. It doesn't introduce any new OOP concept, it doesn't affect the way how we structure our code, it is not really that important. It just lets us remove some boilerplate code if we decided to have a single-function interface and we would like to create implementations of this interface easily with lambda syntax. This is all it does.